# Is there an elegant way to do the equivalent of nested Task.WhenAlls?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I often have code where I have a collection of idependent tasks that create collections of other independent tasks that can be immediately kicked off, so it looks like the following in terms of time.

```
A0 -------
          B0 --------- C0 --------- ...
          B1 ------ C1 ------------ ...
          B2------------------- C2  ...

A1 ---
      B3 -------- C3--------------- ...
      B4  -- C4 ------------------- ...
```

What I do is usually have nested methods like

```
.
.
.
await Task.WhenAll(A0, A1)
.
.
.

private static async ExecuteA(Task A)
{
     var results = await A;
     var BsS = results.Select(r => ExecuteBC(r));
     await Task.WhenAll(BCs);

private static async ExecuteBC(string value)
{
     var result = await ExecuteB(value);
     await ExecuteC(result);
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to chain nested async tasks?

Comment: I think you should remove the concept of Task C from this question, it seems unrelated to having nested WhenAll?

Comment: It'd be nice to have a [mcve] of what you're able to achieve so that we can then present options that replicate the working code. Could you do that please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took your basic example code and fleshed it out until it produced a result:

```
async Task Main()
{
    string[] a0_source = new[] { "Hello", "World" };
    string[] a1_source = new[] { "Hi", "There" };

    Task<string[]> A0 = ExecuteA(a0_source);
    Task<string[]> A1 = ExecuteA(a1_source);

    var results = await Task.WhenAll(A0, A1);

    var output = String.Join(", ", results.SelectMany(x => x));

    Console.WriteLine(output);
}

private static async Task<string[]> ExecuteA(string[] A)
{
    var BCs = A.Select(r => ExecuteBC(r));
    return await Task.WhenAll(BCs);
}

private static async Task<string> ExecuteBC(string value)
{
    var result = await ExecuteB(value);
    return await ExecuteC(result);
}

private static async Task<string> ExecuteC(string value)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => value + "!C");
}

private static async Task<string> ExecuteB(string value)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => value + "!B");
}
```

This produces `Hello!B!C, World!B!C, Hi!B!C, There!B!C` on the console.

I then introduced Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "System.Reactive") and produced this intermediate result:

```
async Task Main()
{
    string[] a0_source = new[] { "Hello", "World" };
    string[] a1_source = new[] { "Hi", "There" };

    IObservable<string> query =
        from a in a0_source.Concat(a1_source).ToObservable()
        from b in Observable.FromAsync(() => ExecuteB(a))
        from c in Observable.FromAsync(() => ExecuteC(b))
        select c;

    var output = String.Join(", ", await query.ToArray());

    Console.WriteLine(output);
}

private static async Task<string> ExecuteC(string value)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => value + "!C");
}

private static async Task<string> ExecuteB(string value)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => value + "!B");
}
```

You can then take it one step further and do this:

```
async Task Main()
{
    string[] a0_source = new[] { "Hello", "World" };
    string[] a1_source = new[] { "Hi", "There" };

    IObservable<string> query =
        from a in a0_source.Concat(a1_source).ToObservable()
        from b in Observable.Start(() => a + "!B")
        from c in Observable.Start(() => b + "!C")
        select c;

    var output = String.Join(", ", await query.ToArray());

    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

It seems fairly elegant now. The best bit is that you can easily convert an observable into a task with a simple `.ToTask()` call. Observables are also awaitable. It's an easy drop in replacement that's a lot more elegant. The best thing is that it uses LINQ syntax too. Let me know if you need more explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If `Task A` doesn't need to process anything after it's set of `Task Bs` are complete, then you could return an `IEnumerable<Task>`, and await all of them.

```
await Task.WhenAll(ExecuteA(A0).Concat(ExecuteA(A1)))

...

private static async Task<IEnumerable<Task>> ExecuteA(Task task)
{
    var results = await task;
    return results.Select(r => ExecuteB(r));
}

private static async Task ExecuteB(string value)
{
    ...
}
```

If you need to process the result of ExecuteB inside of ExecuteA then I'd be happy with the code you wrote.

---

As an aside, I find it unusual to pass `Task`s into a method, and usually await outside of the method call.